# javascript bookmarklet to hide all images from current webpage?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

i wanna create a simple bookmarklet that hides all images from the current website i'm browsing.

```
javascript:body.getElementsByTagName("img").style.visibility="hidden";
```

that's not working? i wonder what i'm doing wrong?

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to iterate over the array-like object returned from `document.getElementsByTagName`, e.g.:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

**Edit:**

The complete bookmarklet URI:

```
javascript:(function(){var imgs=document.getElementsByTagName("img");for(var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++)imgs[i].style.visibility="hidden"}());
```

Comment: and how can i use that in one line for a bookmarklet? is that even possible to do?

Comment: Sure, just replace newlines with spaces.

Comment: javascript:var%20imgs=document.getElementsByTagName("img");for(var%20i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){imgs[i].style.visibility="hidden";}

Comment: doesn't work for me! clears the whole page and adds "hidden" to the body!

Comment: thank you! but it doesn't really do the trick on every page! eg. on google if you browse for images it doesn't hide the images? any idea why?

Comment: This will work on all images when the Bookmarklet is clicked. There is nothing stopping images loading after that (which wasn't specified in the scope of your question) though its possible to do that if you add a 'setInterval' to redo it every few seconds or to insert a CSS rule instead..

Comment: This method (and mine) won't hide images that weren't embedded using `<img>` tags. These would primarily be CSS based images (`background-url`, etc), but it can also be `<embed>`, since images can be embedded using the embed tag.

Comment: @mathiregister: At least in Chrome with the new image search, they are using canvas elements instead of images. If you call `getElementsByTagName` with "canvas" instead of "img" it should work. Of course, you would probably want to do both. Another case you might want to think about is CSS background images.

Answer (score 0):

my problem is this image-banners over the complete page (not interesting). so i was not able to read any text (text is interesting).

set height to 0 or in this example to 60px

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i].style.height = "60px";
}
```

`javascript:(function()%7Bvar%20imgs%20%3D%20document.getElementsByTagName(%22img%22)%3Bfor%20(var%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20imgs.length%3B%20i%2B%2B)%20%7Bimgs%5Bi%5D.style.height%20%3D%20%2260px%22%3B%7D%7D)()`